# How to avoid leaking the loop index into namespace for python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, language-design, python-2.x

```
for i in mylist:
    process(i)

[process(j) for j in mylist]
```

At the end of the execution, `i` and `j` remain in the namespace with the last value of `mylist`.

Other than creating a specialized function to hide `i` from leaking; what are other ways to hide loop indexes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is not much else you can do except explicitly deleting `i` and `j`:

```
for i in mylist:
    process(i)

[process(j) for j in mylist]

print j, i  # -> 8 8
del i, j
print j, i  # NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

a side note: if the list is empty, the variable  remains undefined:

```
for i in []:
    pass
print i  # NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

and one more thing: in python 2.x variables from list-comprehensions (not generator expressions though) are leaked as well; in python 3.x this is a `NameError`.

```
[i for i in range(3)]
print i  #  2
```

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, there is not much you can do about stopping `i` from leaking in a for loop, but if you want to just apply a function over an iterable, like a list, you could use `map(yourFunction, yourList)` instead of a for loop. Then there will not be an i or j to worry about.